# Async-Function-call inside of wpf not working

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, .net-core, async-await

I have the following AsyncFunction:

```
    Public Async Function SwitchOnAsync() As Task

    _JobSwitchIllumination.Parameter_TargetState = True
    Await _JobSwitchIllumination.ExecuteJobAsync()

End Function
```

which internally calls the following function

```
    Public Async Function ExecuteJobAsync() As Task

    Dim TaskExecuteJob As New Task(New Action(AddressOf ExecuteJob))
    TaskExecuteJob.Start()
    Await TaskExecuteJob

    If TaskExecuteJob.IsFaulted = True Then
        Throw TaskExecuteJob.Exception
    End If

End Function
```

Testing those functions inside of a console app both execution modes (sync and async) work well:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Start sync-call")
        Await Plc.ImageUnit.Illuminations.Item(0).SwitchOnAsync()
        Console.WriteLine("Execution finished synchronously")
        
       Console.WriteLine("Start async-call")
        Dim taski As Task = Plc.ImageUnit.Illuminations.Item(0).SwitchOnAsync()
        taski.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(AddressOf WriteFinishedToConsole))

Private Sub WriteFinishedToConsole(ByVal test As Task)

        If test.IsCompletedSuccessfully Then
            Console.WriteLine("Async Execution finished successfully")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Async Execution finished with errors: {0}", test.Exception)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Trying to use the same procedure in a WPF-app (.Net Framework 4.7.2) both versions doesn't work at all.

Test 1:

```
Private async Sub btnEin_Click() Handles btnEin.Click

    Await Illumination.SwitchOnAsync()

End Sub
```

Test2:

```
Private async Sub btnEin_Click() Handles btnEin.Click

    Dim taski As Task = Illumination.SwitchOnAsync()
    taski.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(AddressOf FinishApiCall))

End Sub

Private Sub FinishApiCall(ByVal A As Task)
  
        btnEin.Blinken = False
           
    End Sub
```

Unfortunally both version doesn't work. In both cases the code is executed which I can see from monitoring some i/o-variables but also in both versions the task doesn't seem to get finished at all, because my line after the await / the first line in my FinishApiCall() is never get called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:
As suggested I changed the ExecuteJobAsync-function as following:

```
    Public Async Function ExecuteJobAsync() As Task

    'Dim TaskExecuteJob As New Task(New Action(AddressOf ExecuteJob))
    'TaskExecuteJob.Start()
    'Await TaskExecuteJob

    Dim TaskExecuteJob As Task = Task.Run(New Action(AddressOf ExecuteJob))

    Await TaskExecuteJob

    If TaskExecuteJob.IsFaulted = True Then
        Throw TaskExecuteJob.Exception
    End If

End Function
```

Unfortunally there was no change in the strange behaviour (working in console with .Net-Core 3.1 / not working in WPF with .Net 4.7.2

Edit 2 Code as requested:

```
Public Sub ExecuteJob()

    If _JobIsRunning = True Then
        'Throw New Exception("Can Not start job, because last job isn't finished yet")
        Throw New PlcGatewayException(4711)
    End If

    ParameterDefinieren()

    Me.JobStart = True
    Do While Me.JobStart = True
        'Warten bis das Startbit von der SPS zurückgesetzt wurde
    Loop
    _JobIsRunning = True

    Do While _JobIsRunning = True
    Loop

    RueckgabewerteAuslesen()

    If _CacheJobabschluss <> 0 Then
        Throw New PlcGatewayException(_CacheJobabschluss)
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit 3:

Thanks to @mm8 I found out something new:
I tried the same with a .Net  Framework 4.7.2 Console app and the same problem occoured here so it doesn't seems to be a specific wpf-problem.

If I link that new console app directly to the library it works, but if I install it via a nuget-package the error occours.

My class library is .net-Core 3.1 with an additonal flag for building 4.7.2

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

Also there seems to be a silghtly different behaviour using debug- or release build.

Maybe this new information helps to solve my issue.

Comment: You haven't told us what `btnEin.Blinken` is. However, in btnEin_Click you could simply await the `Illumination.SwitchOnAsync()` call, then call `btnEin.Blinken = False`.

Comment: Hallo @Clemens 
btnEin.Blinken changes the background-color of the button. This is what I tested in Test1: I am awaiting the procedure Illumination.SwitchInAsync() to finish but it´s never finishing. The same call in a console app works like a charm

Comment: I don't really understand VB, but your ExecuteJobAsync method with Start and await looks wrong. You should just be calling Task.Run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the implementation of `ExecuteJob` but you should access the button on the UI thread. Try this:

```
Private async Sub btnEin_Click() Handles btnEin.Click

    Await Illumination.SwitchOnAsync()
    btnEin.Blinken = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but the code doesn't work, because the line btnEin.Blinken = false is never executed. ExecuteJob is an synchronous method wrapped inside an async-method inside ExecuteJobAsync(). Please see the code in Edit2.

Comment: @Stef: If you step through the code in the debugger, where does it stop?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't tell you, because I am not able to debug the code. But with your help I found out something new. Please see my Edit 3.